# Make code dynamic/lighter using concatenation and Jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, custom-data-attribute

I've been looking around for ways to make this VERY explicit block of code I have more dynamic. Code and more explanation below:

HTML first:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><span id="home-btn">Home</span></li>
            <li><span id="work-btn">Work</span></li>
            <li><span id="contact-btn">Contact</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I didn't feel the need to paste the actual content DIVs, appropriately ID'ed as `#home`, `#work`, `#contact`, each have a class with the same name as their IDs, as well as shared class called `.page`. The reason I've used `<span>` instead of `<a>` tags there was because the anchors kept reloading the page and causing issues.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('div#home').show();
    $('div#work, div#contact').hide();
 });

$('#home-btn').click(function(){

    $('#home').show();
    $('.page').not('#home').hide();

});

$('#work-btn').click(function(){

    $('#work').show();
    $('.page').not('#work').hide();

});

$('#contact-btn').click(function(){

    $('#contact').show();
    $('.page').not('#contact').hide();

});
```

As you can see my code is very redundant, and I want to make it more dynamic. My initial attempts tried to concatenate selectors, but I am still novice with JS and wasn't able to get a solution that worked. My next attempt tried to use the `.data` HTML attribute and JQuery method, but I wasn't able to get that to work either. I've used different `.addClass`, `removeClass`, and `hasClass` methods to add `.active` and `.hidden` classes to the elements `.onClick`. That solution got me closest, but didn't function as I would like.

My biggest challenge has been: how do I associate the "buttons" that listen for the click events to know which divs to show or hide (that's where my use of the data attribute came in)... some other solutions I've researched but haven't tried (simply because I don't know how to customize them for my code) were `.split`, `.each`, and using `this`.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would change up your html just a little bit like this:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-content="#home">Home</span></li>
        <li><span data-content="#work">Work</span></li>
        <li><span data-content="#contact">Contact</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now each span has a way to reference its element you want to show.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.page').hide();
    $('#home').show();
 });
```

ID attributes should be unique, so there is no reason you need to do `div#id`, you can just do `#id`

Now for the dynamic part:

```
$('.main-nav').find('span').on('click', function()
    {
        $('.page').hide(); //hide all the content
        $( $(this).attr('data-content') ).show(); //grab the reference we set up in data-cotnent and show that element.
    }
)};
```

Comment: Is there any reason for  `$('.main-nav').find('span')` ? `$('.main-nav span')` will also do the job right? :)

Comment: Yup, either works. But I think `.find()` is (negligibly) faster? http://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again

Comment: Yes, but if look in the later versions of the browser the selector is faster , so almost equal i must say:)

Comment: Do I need to add the same 'data-content' to my <div>s as well?

Comment: I did, I'll test by removing them. Either way, this worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Also, I know this isn't necessarily the place, but I still don't understand how it knows to connect the data-content with the ID (seeing as how they are the same, I'm assuming that's where the match occurs). Especially because the code works even without the `data-content` on each of the <div>s.

Comment: I'm just using data-content to store the selector to match the other div that you want shown when it's clicked. When you click a span, i'm grabbing the selector. You don't need to add anything to the divs. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @alex.mo.07 : Its just to load the selector , u can either use that along with # like `#home` or append an `#` to `home` , hope you are getting what i am trying to say ?

Comment: Yes that makes sense, so essentially (in trying to understand the "data" attribute itself) you can really use it however you want to create an association with another element on the page? Thanks for all the help, folks! :)

Comment: You can use it store any kind of data you want really. You can even make up an attribute like `<span open="#id">` but if your attribute begins with `data-` it will validate as HTML5, whereas made up attributes won't.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

You can also use `<a>` instead of `<span>` , to counter the reload issues use property `href='javascript:void(0)';`

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><span load="home" id="home-btn">Home</span></li>
            <li><span load="work" id="work-btn">Work</span></li>
            <li><span load="contact" id="contact-btn">Contact</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**JS:**

Give a class to all those content divs you want to load say '`.page`', so it would easier for you to hide them.

```
$('nav ul li span').click(function(){
   var load = $(this).attr('load');
   $('.page').hide();
   $('#'+load).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the data-* attribute in your  tag:

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><span data-target="home"    id="home-btn">Home</span></li>
        <li><span data-target="work"    id="work-btn">Work</span></li>
        <li><span data-target="contact" id="contact-btn">Contact</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**JS:**

```
$('nav ul li span').click(function(){
    var load = $(this).data('target');
    $('.page').hide();
    $('#'+load).show();
});
```

The data-* works on all major browsers, including older versions of IE.